# Every finite group contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and $p$ a prime number. Write $n=p^rm$ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$ such that $m\not\in p\mathbb{Z}$. Let
$$E=\{X\subset G\ :\ |X|=p^r\}.$$
Then $|E|=\binom{n}{p^r}$; since $\binom{n}{p^r}\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, it follows that $|E|\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$.

Let $G$ act on itself by left translation: i.e. the map $\gamma:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_G,\,g\mapsto(h\mapsto gh)$, is a homomorphism. Extend this action canonically to $\mathfrak{P}(G)$. Since $E$ is stable under this action, the map
$$\varphi:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_E,\,g\mapsto(X\mapsto gX),$$
is a homomorphism.

> There exists $X\in E$ whose orbit has non-zero cardinal mod $p$.

**Attempt:**

$p^r\leq n$ implies that $\binom{n}{p^r}\ne0$; hence, $E\ne\emptyset$. Let $X\in E$. Then $X\subset G$ and $|X|=p^r$. Obviously $\text{orb}(X)$ is nonempty. But why should it be the case that $$|\text{orb}(X)|\not\equiv 0\ \pmod{p}?$$

Comment: You can't show an _arbitrary_ element of $E$ meets this condition, you can only show such an element exists. Think about $|E|$...